# Format Logging message in GCP Logging Python

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I would like to format the logging message on GCP Logging the way I'm doing locally using Python's native logging (showing the function name, for instance). Suppose my Cloud Function's name is `cloud_function_name()` and it calls another function within called `validate_schema()`.

The result I'm getting when running the Cloud Function locally (and what I expect to see on GCP Logging):

```
root - [INFO] - [validate_schema] -  [29-Jun-21 08:25:21] - Validation was successful.
```

Using the same code snippet and using `google.cloud.logging` library what I'm getting in GCP Logging is:

```
Info - 2021-06-28 15:59:38.428 ART - cloud_function_name - 2m3oxh224fzi - Validation was successful.
```

Is there any possibility to format the logs in GCP Logging to show the function name, not only the cloud function name, but the functions within it?

Comment: Where is the code that creates the log entry?

Comment: Have you looked at [formatting errors](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages) doc? Does it answer your question?